# Project root folder path in Python

Tags: python

I have a python project `$MY_PROJECT` where the python notebooks are in the folder `$MY_PROJECT/Analysis/src/notebooks`, and the python files are in `$MY_PROJECT/Analysis/src/notebooks/scripts`.

Inside each notebook, I have these instructions to load the python files that are in the scripts folder. Later, I import the method in the notebook, like it is shown below.

```
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('./scripts'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from scripts.parser import load_static_data
```

Inside the `scripts` folder, there is a file (`parser.py`) with the `__main__` method. I decided in this file to not append the scripts module to the `sys.path` because the file is already located in the `scripts` folder.

If I try to run the `parser.py` in the command line, I get the error below.

```
python scripts/parser.py input1 ./output-folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scripts.data_loading import load_static_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

How can I define that every time I run a python file or a notebook, the classes are loaded from the project root folder (i.e., `$MY_PROJECT`)?

Comment: if parser.py is in scripts/, and data_loading.py is in scripts; then in parser.py, you just need to use ```from .data_loading import load_static_data``` and then add a __init__.py to your scripts/ dir.

Comment: I already have a `__init__.py`  inside the `scripts` folder.

Comment: then it'd just be ```from .data_loading import load_static_data```